# Method of finding radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Hi is it acceptable to evaluate the radius of convergence $R$ of this power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-\frac{2}{3}}x^{n}$$ by instead of taking $a_{n} := (-1)^{n}n^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ we take $a_{n} := (-1)^{n}n^{-\frac{2}{3}}x^{n}$ which results in: 
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|x(\frac{n}{n+1})^{\frac{2}{3}}| = x$$

The result being that the radius of convergence is always the coefficient of $x$. Is this an acceptable adaptation of the usual method of finding the radius of convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Ratio_test) for convergence says that you need to get
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| < 1$$

You already showed that the limit is $|x|$, so you just need 
$$|x|<1$$

Therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Okay thanks, I just wanted to confirm that this is equivalent method as to where you simply take $a_{n} := (-1)^{n}n^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ and evaluate the radius of convergence by taking the limit of $|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|$.

Comment: Is the radius of convergence sensitive to whether you take $\lim\limits|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$ or $\lim\limits|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|$?

Comment: @Alex: The usual way is to use the first ratio. I edited my answer to make that more clear (see the link). One reason this way is better is that you may get $\lim\limits|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|=0$; the reciprocal will get no limit. The other way would then be more complicated to allow that one lack of limit but disallow other lacks of limits.

Comment: Do you know of an example of a power series where $\lim\limits|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| = 0$ and no limit for reciprocal? Do you think it would be possible to take the limit $\lim\limits\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ without absolute value and just take the absolute value of the coefficient of $x$. In this example I would get $-x$ and then take the absolute value which would give $R = 1$. What do you think?

Comment: @Alex: The series for $e^x$, namely $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}$ has $\lim|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| = \lim |\frac1{n+1}|=0$, but the limit of the reciprocal is obviously infinity. You should *not* take the limit without absolute value: many alternating series would then not give a limit.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your assistance. You say that the convention is $\lim\limits |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$ but in this wiki entry {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence} it states that the second limit is used to denote the radius of convergence. What do you think?

Comment: The line to which you refer is not the ratio test but rather a calculation of the radius of convergence. The very next line *does* refer to the ratio test and that line uses the standard $n+1$ on top. Is that clear?

Comment: Yes I see for the ratio test it is inverted but my question is regarding calculation of the radius of convergence in particular, so then the limit $\lim\limits|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|$ would be the one to use?

Comment: Yes, for that calculation put $a_{n+1}$ on the bottom. If the resulting limit is $+\infty$ then the radius of convergence is infinity, meaning that the series converges for all real numbers.

Comment: Okay thanks, having said that would you consider it incorrect to consider $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$ instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18502/discussion-between-rory-daulton-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

You should **always** use this method to find the radius of convergence.

As you stated:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{-\frac{2}{3}}x^{n}$$

When conducting the root test, you **must** include the variable $x$. Otherwise your radius of convergence either will never convergence or be $\infty$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|(-1)^{n}n^{-\frac{2}{3}}x^{n}\right|^{1/n} = \left|x\right|$$

The limit only converges when it is $< 1$. Therefore, $|x| < 1$, and the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Okay thanks, I just wanted to confirm that this is equivalent method as to where you simply take $a_{n} := (-1)^{n}n^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ and evaluate the radius of convergence by taking the limit of $|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|$.

Comment: if you are content with the answer, either upvote or check so users can know you question is answered.